# Android Things Raspberi Pi Not booting

Tags: android, raspberry-pi3, android-things

I'm new to Android Things, so would beg your pardon for any silly mistake.
I'm using Raspberi Pi 3 Model B, and installed Android Things 0.5.1-devpreview on the sd card. But it's not booting. The board is fine as it's working fine with NOOBS and LIBREElec. When I start the board with Android Things it just shows the rainbow image of raspberi two times before shutting down.
Please help.
I've downloaded the zip from https://partner.android.com/things/console/#/622pn5/build and unzipped it (using fedora, so unzipped using Archive Manager), and Flashed the image to SD Card using [Etcher](https://etcher.io/).
I'm just unable to boot Android Things in Raspberi Pi, this problem doesn't includes any coding (but a development related problem), so I've not pasted any code here.
Again beg your pardon for any stupidity as I'm new to Android Things.

Comment: Display was working fine with NOOBS and LibreElec

Comment: Switched to 0.4.1-devpreview, working fine. The problem still not resolved for 0.5.1-devpreview.

Comment: Have you tried connecting to the RPI with a serial connection and watching the logs? I've had boot problems on various Android Things devices and that's been helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Try a different power source. I noticed when I used one that's too low for the board the board wouldnt boot up.

Comment: The same power source was working fine with NOOBS and LibreElec. Though checked with new power source based on your suggestion, but didn't worked.

Comment: I'm late in my responsive but also check the format of your sd card. The sd card has to be formatted in ms-dos(FAT32) in order for the Android Things boot up at least in my experience. Hopefully, you already resolved your issue and this comment isn't needed.

Comment: Its working fine with 0.4.1 the problem is only with 0.5.1

Answer (score 0):

try using dd to put the image in sd.

It worked for me.

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/

Comment: Please expand on your answer with the specific command.  Your answer should stand on its own without the link.

Comment: for linux use:  "dd bs=4M if=iot_rpi3.img of=/dev/sdX conv=fsync" 

ref: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/linux.md