# Raspberi Pi3 board is not booting : Android Things

Tags: android, raspberry-pi3, iot, android-things, android-things-console

I'm an Android app developer and have tried Android Things.

After flashing image to the card, my Raspberry Pi 3 board is not booting up (i.e. it does not show anything). I have already tried the answers in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46036082/android-things-raspberi-pi-not-booting) and [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46123900/android-things-0-5-1-boot-failed-on-raspberry-pi-3) as they mentioned it could be due to SD card class.

SD card I am using is of class 10.

For putting the Android image I am using the [official Linux image](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/linux.md), but it is still not working. Has anyone managed to get it to work?

Comment: How did you flash the image to the device?

Comment: What format is your SD Card in?

Comment: what version of AT are you flashing?

Comment: @webo80 using dd command

Comment: @Private_GER fat32

Comment: @Blundell using latest 0.5.1

Comment: Can you check the MD5? Maybe your download is corrupt.

Comment: You might want to consider investigating `dmesg` and `logcat` messages by [connecting to serial console](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43554006/3290339) to see what's going on.